# Failed to add API

Tags: android

I followed the instuctions on
https://github.com/igdb/api-android-java/blob/master/README.md
and got this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
>   Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support.test:runner' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (0.5) and test app (1.0.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

build.gradle project

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ofirv.gamesugest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.igdb:api-android-java:master-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line     `compile 'com.github.igdb:api-android-java:master-SNAPSHOT'` by the code below : (It should work. I have tested it for you)

```
  implementation ('com.github.igdb:api-android-java:master-SNAPSHOT'){
        exclude module: 'runner'
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, can you tell me what you did?

Comment: You are welcome ! I excluded the conflicted dependency which is 'com.android.support.test:runner from the module  'com.github.igdb:api-android-java:master-SNAPSHOT'.